# hostname -f returns incorrect information. information that applies to another server

Tags: domain-name-system, hostname

I have a server that has been working just fine with the correct hostname since i set it up several months ago, but now, it thinks it's hostname has changed.

It started as `hostnamea.example.com` but is now identifying itself as `otherhostname.example.com`. That is, the hostname at the beginning of the line in the shell is changed, the output of `hostname -f` is changed etc. the contents of `/etc/hostname` are still the same though. I have also checked `/etc/hosts` and there is an entry for `127.0.1.1` for `hostnamea.example.com`

The thing is, there is another server called otherhostname.example.com.
that server returns the correct information from `hostname -f`

I have checked and rechecked the DNS configuration and there is no error.

The two servers are on completely different networks from different ISPs. The first one is on a static IP address from a residential broadband provider and one is in a datacentre.

So, any idea's what I've inadvertently messed up?

Comment: can you please run the following command and pastebin the output? > strace hostname -f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with DNS. The host name usually is only set once when the network comes up.
Someone probably changed it by accident, just change it back.

```
hostname hostnamea
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked, strange thing is i wouldn't have done that myself and no-one else is supposed to have access to the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, is there an incorrect /etc/hosts entry for one of the proper IP addresses assigned to your server?  Or, barring that, an incorrect reverse lookup entry in your DNS server?


--Christopher Karel

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that someone simply changed it via "hostname otherhostname.domain.tld" by accident?